# Opening a file through a drop down menu in python

Tags: python, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to find a way to open a file through a drop down menu in python yet i haven't been able to find anything this is the code.
Any assistance would be heavily appreciated and do me some amazing help.

```
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter as ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Tk dropdown example')

root.configure(background="white") 
root.geometry("400x400") 

mainframe = Frame(root)
mainframe.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.pack(pady = 100, padx = 100)

tkvar = StringVar(root)

choices = {'1946', '1947', '1948', '1949', '1950'}
tkvar.set ('1946 - 1950')

popupMenu = OptionMenu (mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
popupMenu.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

tkvar = StringVar(root)

choices = {'1941', '1942', '1943', '1944', '1945'}
tkvar.set ('1941 - 1945')

popupMenu = OptionMenu (mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
Label(mainframe, text='Choose a Year').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
popupMenu.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

tkvar = StringVar(root)

choices = {'1936', '1937', '1938', '1939', '1940'}
tkvar.set ('1936 - 1940')

popupMenu = OptionMenu (mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
popupMenu.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post links for the documents/tutorials that you have already reviewed. This way, others will know what approaches you've taken toward solving this problem.

Comment: Read [dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs)